# rake route - No route matches [GET] "/" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

On visiting `localhost:3000` I'm getting the typical:

> No route matches [GET] "/"

I don't want to see that error screen. I already trying with `localhost:3000/passbook/v1/passes/` but still nothing so I typed:

```
rake routes
```

and got this output:

```
passbook GET    /passbook/v1/passes/:pass_type_identifier/:serial_number(.:format)                                           passbook/passes#show {:pass_type_identifier=>/([\w\d]\.?)+/}
             GET    /passbook/v1/devices/:device_library_identifier/registrations/:pass_type_identifier(.:format)                passbook/registrations#index {:pass_type_identifier=>/([\w\d]\.?)+/}
             POST   /passbook/v1/devices/:device_library_identifier/registrations/:pass_type_identifier/:serial_number(.:format) passbook/registrations#create {:pass_type_identifier=>/([\w\d]\.?)+/}
             DELETE /passbook/v1/devices/:device_library_identifier/registrations/:pass_type_identifier/:serial_number(.:format) passbook/registrations#destroy {:pass_type_identifier=>/([\w\d]\.?)+/}
passbook_log POST   /passbook/v1/log(.:format)                                                                                   passbook/logs#create
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Add this line: `root :to => "passbook/passes#show"`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told Rails yet what your root path is. You can do this by saying

```
root to: "passes#show"
```

in config/routes.rb. Afterwards, you should see this in the `rake routes` output:

```
root      /      passes#show
```

Then it should work!

---

#### Additional tip

This may be over the top for your question, but following the test driven approach you should write a spec first:

```
describe "custom routing" do
    it "shows the root page" do
        get("/").should route_to("passes#show")
    end
end
```

Use [RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec) for this. Run the test in your console *before having written the route itself* by doing `$ rspec` and see the test fail at the right place.

Then, implement the routes above, run the test again—it should work. This way you ensure that you have written just enough code to meet your requirements, and that it is really the code you have written that lets you access the root path.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a rails app you inherited from someone else?

Given the `rake routes` output you have provided, a url like `localhost:3000/passbook/v1/passes/<EXAMPLE_PASS_TYPE_IDENTIFIER>/<EXAMPLE_SERIAL_NUMBER>` should work based on the rule in the first line of the output, provided you replace `EXAMPLE_PASS_TYPE_IDENTIFIER` and `EXAMPLE_SERIAL_NUMBER` with valid values from the database.

The error message `No route matches [GET] "/` for `localhost:3000` is because there is no mapping for `root` in `rake routes` output.

You could modify the `config/routes.rb` file and add the following line at the bottom of the file:

`root :to => "<controller_name>#<action_name>"`

Eg:

```
root :to => "passbook/index"
```

if there is a `passbooks_contoller.rb` with a `index` method.

Best to learn more about [rails routing from the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Even better go through [the Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) to get a good understanding of the rails framework.